# Alternative to Facebook Static FBML

Tags: web-applications, facebook-graph-api

Am developing an e-commerce website and would like to add a "facebook like" button for each page on the website. After searching I found that FBML (which will like the current page) is what I really wanted but it is now deprecated . What alternatives are there to using FBML if I want to like a URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The like button uses (**X**)FBML not FBML. So Facebook plugins are not deprecated.

Anyway, you can always use the other versions of the [plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/), IFrame or HTML5.

Comment: Using the XFBML seems as if I have to manually add a button per unique page URL. I wanted a plugin to like the current item page once the page is available. I might just have to find an alternative. But thanks for you suggestion.

Comment: I didn't understand you here.

Comment: I meant: do I have to go on facebook and manually generate a like button for each product page on my web site?

Comment: Well, if you use the XFBML version you don't need to specify the `href` parameter. So you can use the same code in all your templates. Now if you have a static website (your pages are not created dynamically) then yeah, regardless of the plugin version...you'll have to copy the plugin yourself!